# SConstruct 101—moving on from Makefiles

Tags: scons

Like
[`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html),
[`scons`](https://scons.org/doc/4.1.0.post1/HTML/scons-user/index.html) has a large number of predefined variables and rules. (Try `scons | wc` on an `SConstruct` containing `env = Environment(); print(env.Dump())` to see how extended the set is.)

But suppose we aren't after the wizardry of presets but rather want to do something a lot more primitive—simulating launching a few instructions from the (bash, etc) command line?

Also suppose we're quite happy with the default `Decider('MD5')`. What is the translation of the one-souce-one-target:

```
out/turquoise.xyz: out/chartreuse.xyz
    chartreuse_to_turquoise $< $@
```

of the two-source-one-target:

```
out/purple.xyz: out/lilac.xyz out/salmon.xyz
    gen_purple $< $@
```

and of:

```
run_this:
    python prog.py
```

which we would run on-demand by typing `make run_this`?

What does the `SConstruct` for these elementary constructs look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the answers you're looking for are in the users guide (and manpage)

Firstly, assuming you don't want to scan the input files to add included files  specified in the input files, you can use `Commmand()`
(See info here: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-builders-commands)

Then you'll want an alias to specify an a non file command line target
(See here:https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-alias)

Putting those two together yields

```
env=Environment()
# one source, one target
env.Command('out/turquoise.xyz', 'out/chartreuse.xyz', 'chartreuse_to_turquoise $SOURCE $TARGET')
# Two source, one target
env.Command('out/purple.xyz',['out/lilac.xyz','out/salmon.xyz'], 'gen_purple $SOURCES $TARGET')

# And your .phony make target which is actually not great for reproducibility and determining when it should be rerun, because you do not specify any sources or targets
env.Alias('run_this','python prog.py')
```

Note: SCons doesn't NOT propagate your shell environment variables. So if you depend on (for example) a non system path in your PATH, you'll need to explicitly specify that in env['ENV']['PATH'] for example.  For more details take a read through the users guide, manpage and FAQ.

- https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html
- https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html
- https://scons.org/faq.html

And you can reach the community directly via our [discord server](https://discord.gg/bXVpWAy), [IRC channel](https://scons.org/contact.html), or users mailing list

Comment: After reading
[through](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/index.html)
to Chapter 7 (Environments), I was puzzled to not have encountered the answer to this elementary question. I see now that I would have had to wait until
[Appendix B. Builders](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/apb.html) to find it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Re "scan the input files": consider a workflow that runs a few awk, sed, and python scripts. They all take text (or JSON, or mark-up/down, or...). The question is how to manage it with scons.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that you'd have to wait til the appendix. The links above for Command and and Alias are chapters 18 and 23 respectively.

Comment: @sam - none of awk, sed, and python scripts would always pull in other source files when processing by default.  When I say "scan the input files", It's for things like header files included in C files via #include directives.

Comment: Re "none of ..", "for things like .." yes, yes, of course. That's exactly my point. BTW, I love the tool, so far, and after just one day. I just hope the documentation would not talk for so long about how much wizardry there is, that it would discuss the elementary case I describe sooner. But I should be patient until chaps 18-23.

Comment: It's a users guide, not a quick start guide.. ;)

Comment: If this resolves your question, please mark it the answer/solution?